# Swift Response template without additional casting

Tags: swift

Do somebody know how to achieve Template on Response but without extra casting? Now if I do so Xcode returns me error that I can't override T dynamically. But I really believe I on right way but missed something. No?

Now it's looks like: `func didReciveResponse(request: Request, response: Response<Any>)`

```
    enum Response<T> {
        case success(response: T)
        case failured(error: Error)
    }

    func pseudoResponse() {
        let time: Timeinterval = 3
        // somehow cast T (compiler shows error that I can't do this)
        let response = .success<Timeinterval>(time)
        didReciveResponse(.time, response)
    }

    // delegate method
    func didReciveResponse(request: Request, response: Response) {
        switch request {
            case .time:
            switch response {
                // response without additional casting (as?)
                case .success(let value): time = value
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the compiler cannot infer the generic type you have to annotate the type in this case

```
func pseudoResponse() {
    let time: TimeInterval = 3.0
    let response : Response<TimeInterval> = .success(response: time)
    didReciveResponse(request: .time, response: response)
}
```

and you have to specify the `Response` type in the delegate method

```
func didReciveResponse(request: Request, response: Response<TimeInterval>) { ...
```

However if you want to make `didReciveResponse` (actually `didReceiveResponse`) also generic you need to write

```
func didReciveResponse<T>(request: Request, response: Response<T>) {
```